# How to terminate a program in Perl - exit or die?

Tags: perl

I am using syntax checking to see whether my Perl script is being used in the correct way. If the syntax is not correct, I display a message saying what the correct syntax is, and then end the execution of the program.

Between:

```
print "Please use the following syntax: ...";
exit 1;
```

and:

```
die("Please use the following syntax: ...");
```

Which one should I use? I know `die` would have been the answer if exception handling was in place, but that is not the case.

Which one is the better choice for program termination without exception handling?  Please also say why.

Comment: It's worth noting that `die` automatically appends the filename and line number *unless* the error string ends with a newline `"\n"`.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It depends on what you want to have happen with STDERR and STDOUT.   I prefer to send error and warning type messages to STDERR so that when someone is trying to redirect output to a file they still see the error messages; However, there are times though when STDOUT is used to communicate status to the user so he or she can `tail -f` or paginate it, and at those times writing to STDERR causes them pain (they have to redirect STDERR back into STDOUT with `2>&1`, and not everyone knows how to do that).  So which to use, `die` or `print` and `exit`, depends heavily on what type of program you are writing.

There are other benefits/drawbacks to using `die`:

- You can trap `die` with an `eval`, but not exit
- You can run code when the program calls `die` by installing a signal handler for the `__DIE__` signal
- You can easily override the `die` function

Each of those has times where it is handy to be able to do them, and times when it is a pain that they can be done.

Comment: What if you `warn` the error message and then use `exit`? Would you consider that getting the best of both?

Comment: @Arc676 Given that the `warn` writes to STDERR as well I don't see how that could be better than `print` and `exit` in the scenario I described.  It is important to remember that there is no "best"; there are only behaviors that can be beneficial/harmful in certain circumstances.  In general, the right answer is to `die` as that allows for the most flexibility in the program, but you have to keep in mind how the user of the program will be consuming the output.

Answer (score 23):

`print` prints to `STDOUT` but `die` prints to `STDERR`

`exit 1` exits with exit status of `1` but `die` exits with exit current value of `errno` that is `$!`

Hence `die` is the preferred way as its simpler and shorter.

Comment: or `$? >> 8` if `$!` is `0`. or 255 if `$? >> 8` is 0.

Comment: [$OS_ERROR](http://p3rl.org/var#%24OS_ERROR), [$CHILD_ERROR](http://p3rl.org/var#%24CHILD_ERROR)

Comment: `$!` is a special variable that exposes the C errno value.  `$?` a special variable that holds information about the last program executed by `system`, backticks, etc. See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24ERRNO and http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24CHILD_ERROR for more information.

Answer (score 7):

It is best to follow existing practice ("rule of least surprise"): [exit with 2 on a fatal error such as a syntax error](http://p3rl.org/Pod::Usage#DESCRIPTION).

Comment: Upvoted for citing rule of least astonishment/surprise!