# What happens as a perl script ends?

Tags: bash, perl, file, exception, die

This question is specific to perl, in the context that I am specifically wondering what happens to file handles (both operated on and not) when at some point the script `die`s with the handles open.

So what operations occur as the execution comes to the final line of the script? Script level? Perl level? Shell level (e.g. bash)? System level (e.g. assume a modern *nix, such as Ubuntu)?

Here's what info I've found so far, though no direct answers:

[Best practices for terminating perl scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601106/how-to-terminate-a-program-in-perl-exit-or-die)

[Ensure custom code is run upon exit in perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433098/execute-some-code-always-before-the-perl-script-ends)

[Why to close file handles in perl (sys buffers)](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=902128)

Perldoc on `die` and `exit` speak mostly of the functions themselves.

Comment: The handles get closed.

Comment: @Mort: the perlmonks link says as much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perl uses a reference counting strategy for garbage collection.  When a variable's reference count reaches 0, any applicable `DESTROY` method is called before releasing its memory to perl's memory management system.

As your program terminates, its remaining variables will go out of scope and have their reference count decremented.  This is the point at which your file handles will close.

When perl is finished with its clean-up, it will exit back to the operating system, at which point its remaining resources will be returned to the OS, and its parent process (perhaps init or a shell) will be informed of its exit status.

---

Where reference counting might go awry: If you create a data structure with circular references, none of the component variables will naturally have their reference count drop to 0 unless you either weaken one of the references or explicitly call its `DESTROY` method.  In this case the variables will persist until program end, at which point perl will `DESTROY` and/or garbage collect everything regardless of its reference count.

Comment: Could you recommend any resources for further exploration/reading of these topics? I found [this](http://perldoc.perl.org/index-internals.html), but it covers a lot of ground.

Comment: @tniles09 If you're using variables no more complex than nested arrays & hashes, then you can simply assume that they will be reaped when their last reference goes out of scope.  If you are using circular data structures, then [this section of perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Circular-References) should be enough.  If you are designing interfaces to C APIs via XS or `Inline::C` then you may be interested in *all* the internals docs to which you've linked.

Comment: Calling `DESTROY` won't cause the reference count to go down to zero. There may not even be a `DESTROY` method to call.

Comment: @BradGilbert I never intended to imply as much.  I'm sorry if I'm easily misunderstood.

Answer (score -1):

Garbage collection will do an expensive mark / sweep operation if your pointers/filehandlers are not appropriately dismissed.

At the perl level is where garbage collection is run. On shell the normal interuptors and error handlers will still receive IO. On the system level the garbage collection will tell system calls to reallocate memory.